# How to structure box model in complex Flexbox layout + swapping elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, styles

At some viewport I want to be able to **swap** some of the divs as shown by the figure below.
I don't want to use workaround such as replicating the same divs here and there and then using `display:none` to hide them, so please don't suggest this solution unless you think it's the only way to achieve so.

**How would you solve this problem using Flexbox? What would the box model be like?**

What I've tried so far:

- playing with `order` CSS selector. But it works only if all the divs are in the same container (doesn't seem to work with this problem).
- A1 and A2 are visually a single item, as suggested by its colour, but I guess I might need to split it in 2

*PS: please note that the problem is NOT how to build any of these layouts themselves  neither how to use media queries.*

[image: LINK TO THE IMAGE]

Comment: You can't do that with Flexbox alone, you need to combine it with float or absolute positioning, and with those you will loose some of the dynamic growth based on each items content. If you can specify which items that can have a fixed height (and scroll if content exceed their height) there might be a solution, and if not, you need either script or use CSS Grid

Comment: Also, you need to update your question with a working code snippet, as those images doesn't say much how the markup is set up.

Comment: Hi LGSon, 

Thanks for your comment - I can't add any snippet since I don't even have an idea of the actual box model yet, that's what I am looking for, the image should be self-explanatory.

Also, comparing your approach with the workaround I mentioned (using `display:none`/`display:block` - which one is the cleanest in your opinion?

Comment: Most experienced users expect a made effort, and since you said you've tried _playing with `order` CSS selector._, we expect that code snippet to be available in the question.